# Minimize all other applications excluding my own program

Tags: java, swing, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to minimize all running applications in Windows when running my own program.
I am using the following code, but it's minimizing the all windows *including* my program.  Is there any way that I can minimize the applications *excluding* my program?

My code is following:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        new String[]{
            "cmd.exe",
            "/c",
            "\"" + System.getenv("APPDATA") +
            "\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\Show Desktop.scf\""});
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried restoring your program after you execute the command?

Comment: how can i restore my application

Comment: What are you using? Swing/AWT/...?

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use JNA, it gives you scores of options to play with windows... 
this is how you do it using JNA. download JNA.jar

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, nameOfWindow); // window title 
User32.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hwnd, 9); // SW_RESTORE
User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd); // bring to front
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to minimize all running applications in windows when running my own program

*Don't* do that.  *Instead*, do either of:

- Call [`setAlwaysOnTop(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29) (and slug it out with every other app. that wants to be always on top).
- Use [Full Screen Exclusive Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/).  You get to (have to) paint every pixel of the screen, other apps. become irrelevant.

Both those solutions are cross-platform & will work for Windows, Linux/Unix & OS X.

Comment: but my requirement is to minimize other applications Mr Andrew

Comment: Exclusive Fullscreen is a horrible idea. Many new games support "windowed fullscreen" for a very good reason!

Answer (score 0):

You can send Windows+D hotkey or Fn + F11 under Mac:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.setAutoDelay(250);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

{ 
Robot r = null;
    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
r.setAutoDelay(250);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
}
```