# Minimize all applications

Tags: java

I'm trying to minimize all open applications, and using the following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec
        (new String[] {
        "cmd.exe", 
        "/c",
        "\"" + System.getenv("APPDATA") + 
        "\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\Show Desktop.scf" + "\""
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the code, nothing happens.

I'm using Windows 7, when I open Internet Explorer the PC crash from some virus reason (maybe there is a connection?)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973185/minimize-all-other-applications-excluding-my-own-program)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I always get angry if some program minimize all windows for me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun the user will have the choice to click or do not on the button that will minimize all the windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to show the desktop, using the Java's `Robot` class.
This class simulates mouse and keyboard inputs.

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code `new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "wmctrl -k on").start();`

note: need to be installed wmctrl on the distribution

Answer (score -1):

Traverse to the following path :  "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\"

and check the "FileName" and its "Extension".

In my case it was : Shows Desktop.lnk

In windows 7 the name changes to "Shows Desktop.lnk"